# User creation and tracking via Spring and Auth0

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, auth0

I have a Resource Server (Spring Boot), where they access it via an access token from Auth0 SSO via Google/Apple/etc. (using React Native on mobile application), which grants authorization. From this, I would like to create a user and/or update this user in my Resource Server to track them to do certain app specific things with my REST API.

The access token would be used on the Resource Server as a Bearer Token. However, I am not fully sure if this is secure compared to other methods.

The main approach I know of is:

1. Using the Auth0 access token that is provided, I obtain user info from Auth0 with the access token by calling server-to-server (Spring to Auth0). This user info - the provider ID, user ID, email - is used to create and update the User Entity.

However, this means making an API call at least for the user's initial or first call to my own Resource Server (to create the User Entity).

Two things I would like to know is A. is this secure with my initial approach idea? B. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that duplicating user data in your own database brings the usual data duplication issues: how do you expect your database to be updated when user data is updated at Auth0?

The easy way to fix that is to keep only a "key" for the user in your database and to fetch user data from Auth0 API when you need it. The "primary key" is the user subject, but you could use another property, provided that it is unique, not null and not modifiable. Of course, this is slower than a local database, but, maybe, you could use some caching.

The other option is to set some hooks in Auth0 to call your resource server when a user is updated, but [this doesn't seem straight forward](https://community.auth0.com/t/automation-trigger-on-user-app-metadata-update/94829).

To read user data in your resource server, you can use the JWT payload (it is "safe") and don't need an additional roundtrip to Auth0. You can even enrich the default claims with Auth0 actions (sample in [my tutorials prerequisites for Auth0](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/auth0.md)).